# How to transpose two column header as row values and make values of these columns comes under another column name or header using Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to make two column header as row values comes under a  new column and also make their values comes under another column header or column name using Python Pandas. I searched about it, but I could not found a solution for this.

First table:
[image]

I want to make table like this :

second table:
[image]

Can anyone give me a solution to solve this.

Comment: see [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: You should read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars = ['name', 'place'], value_vars = ['weight', 'numbers'], var_name = 'measure', value_name = 'measureing_values')

print(df1)



name  place  measure  measureing_values
0   apple  delhi   weight                  2
1  orange     up   weight                  3
2   onion    goa   weight                  4
3   apple  delhi  numbers                  6
4  orange     up  numbers                  8
5   onion    goa  numbers                 25
```

Comment: How it can be write it as an MySQL Query, if the table name is `product`@ragas

Comment: I don't have `mysql` with me. So, I can't run the code to test it before sharing that with you. But this tutorial will help you in pivoting. https://datacharmer.com/downloads/pivot_tables_mysql_5.pdf